# Cucumber report triggers an Error on each Jenkins Build

Tags: maven, jenkins, cucumber, cucumber-java

I have created a new Maven- Jenkins item( Jenkins runs on a linux server) , installed the Cucumber report plugin and HTML publish plugin with the following options :
- HTML publish -> https://www.screencast.com/t/oh0Z5gB7Mpp
- Cucumber report ->  https://www.screencast.com/t/x1Gu1y2coga9 ,

but every time when my Jenkins build is finished, I see this error  :

> ```
> net.masterthought.cucumber.ValidationException: None report file was added!
>     at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportParser.parseJsonFiles(ReportParser.java:60)
>     at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.generateReports(ReportBuilder.java:88)
>     at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.generateReport(CucumberReportPublisher.java:324)
>     at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.perform(CucumberReportPublisher.java:248)
>     at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:79)
>     at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
>     at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
>     at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
>     at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1073)
>     at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1841)
>     at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
>     at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
> ```

Can someone please help me? What am I doing wrong ? :(

Thanks in advance.
Mary

Comment: Can you add your code? How are you running Cucumber and how have you specified the reporter plugin?

Comment: Hi @Marit , locally all my scenarios are successfully - https://www.screencast.com/t/4R8iARdmjEU and cucumber.json file is generated in target.This is my Feature class : `package Featurerunner;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features = "src/test/resources/Features/",
format = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json" }, glue = {"Steps"},  monochrome = true)
public class FeatureRunnerTest {}. `

Comment: Locally you have the .json report, but not html report? Can you specify in Jenkins that you are expecting the .json report instead of the index.html?

Comment: yes, locally I see the json report. From Jenkins, when I try to click the Steps/Failures tabs from cucumber reports I receive every time _This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:xxxx/job/WebCucumber/cucumber_build/cucumber-html-reports/overview-steps.html
HTTP ERROR 404_

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins deletes workspace after every build. You should export the generated report probably by using Export Report plugin. Refer more information on export report plugin at https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Export+Report

Comment: I couldn't find the Export Report plugin... I've added Summary Display plugin but everything is the same ..:|